# Growth Rate of a Logarithmic Functional

Tags: functional-analysis, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I am dealing with the following function which involves a function multiplied by its logarithm, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
g(y) := \lvert p(y)\log p(y)\rvert, \forall y\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

I know that $p(y) = O(\lvert y\rvert^{-\frac{3}{2}})$, which implies that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists\, \lvert y_{\epsilon}\rvert$ such that $p(y)\leq \epsilon$ for all $\lvert y\rvert > \lvert y_{\epsilon}\rvert$. Now, I want to know the growth rate of $g(y)$. My intuition tells me that $g(y) = O(\lvert y\rvert^{-r})$, where $r>1$. However, I am not able to show this rigorously and I am wondering whether my intuition is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(y) = O(|y|^{-3/2}\log|y|^{-3/2}) = O(|y|^{-3/2}\log|y|) = O(|y|^{-3/2+\epsilon})$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$. This follows by the power rule for logarithms, and the fact that $\log x = O(x^{\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, clearly as long as $\epsilon - 1.5 > -1$, we have the desired property. However, can we say anything about the growth rate of $\lvert p(y)\log p(y) \rvert$ in terms of $p(y)$, i.e., can we say that $g(y) = O(p(y)^{k})$, where $k<1$?

Comment: Well, $O(|y|^{-3/2+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ is equivalent to $O((|y|^{-3/2})^{1-\epsilon}) = O(p(y)^{1-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. In other words, you are correct, it's $O(p(y)^k)$ for any $k < 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This answers my question!

Comment: @MortezaSoltani Glad to help.